# Are there any issues in this `Lazy` implementation?

Tags: java, lazy

I have written following small utility to abstract away the lazy initialization logic. (I tend to use lazy variables quite often.)

Are there any issues in this implementation?

```
// File: F0.java
public abstract class F0<A> {
  public abstract A apply();
}

// File: Lazy.java
public class Lazy<A> {
  private boolean isInitialized = false;
  private A content;
  private final F0<A> init;

  private Lazy(F0<A> init) {
    this.init = init;
  }

  public static <A> Lazy<A> initializedAs(F0<A> init) {
    return new Lazy<A>(init);
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return this.get().toString();
  }

  public A get() {
    if (!isInitialized) {
      content = init.apply();
      isInitialized = true;
    }
    return content;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) {
      return true;
    }
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) {
      return false;
    }
    Lazy lazy = (Lazy) o;
    Object c = this.get();
    if (c != null ? !c.equals(lazy.get()) : lazy.get() != null) {
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
    return this.get().hashCode();
  }
}
```

**Edit:**

Here is an example usage from the current project I am working on.

```
final Prerequisite prerequisite = new Prerequisite() {

  private Lazy<String> minimumRequiredJavaVersion = Lazy.initializedAs(
    new F0<String>() {
      @Override
      public String apply() {
        return SystemProperties.isWindows() && SystemProperties.is64Bit() ? "1.7" : "1.6";
      }
    }
  );

  @Override
  public boolean isSatisfied() {
    return SystemProperties.javaVersionIsMinimum(minimumRequiredJavaVersion.get());
  }

  @Override
  public String failureMessage() {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("Minimum required Java version is: " + minimumRequiredJavaVersion.get() + "\n");
    sb.append("Your system has " + JAVA_SPECIFICATION_VERSION + ".");
    return sb.toString();
  }
};
```

Comment: Samples of how you use it would be appreciated.

Comment: @blufox, I added an example. Basically, the variable is not initialized until it is required. (And not initialized at all if it is not required.) After computing it once, it is cached and this cached value is returned on further accesses.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the question, but... do you know Scala? I found the language quite interesting (functional-oriented, so lazyness is part of the language), it runs in the JVM too and is completely interoperable with Java.

Comment: @kaoD, I have been a Scala enthusiast for more than 2 years, have been professionally working with it since past 1 year, and am one of the [top answeres in Scala tag on stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/scala/topusers) (with a gold badge). :-)

Comment: @kaoD, the current project however is in Java. (Team decision.) So I am trying to replicate some abstractions from Scala that I find indispensable.

Comment: Similar question from stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7524423/lazy-loading-reference-implementation.

Answer (score 2):

Four notes:

1. It's not thread-safe. `init.apply()` could be called multiple times from different threads. (I don't know whether it is an issue or not.)
2. The constructor should check `null` inputs. (*Effective Java 2nd Edition, Item 38: Check parameters for validity*)
3. You should use `append` instead of `String` concatenation:

   ```
   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
   sb.append("Minimum required Java version is: ").append(minimumRequiredJavaVersion.get()).append("\n");
   sb.append("Your system has ").append(JAVA_SPECIFICATION_VERSION).append(".");
   return sb.toString();
   ```
4. Instead of the anonymous `Prerequisite` inner class I'd use a named top-level class (for example, `MinimumRequiredJavaVersionPrerequisite`). I think it's easier to read, naming it helps readers to understand the purpose of the class.

Comment: 1. Indeed. Should I put it in a synchronized block?

Comment: 3. Actually, I was planning to get rid of `StringBuilder`. Java optimizes this stuff anyway.

Comment: 4. Personal matter of taste. The code follows a functional programming style, and therefore anonymous inner classes are abound.

Comment: Overall, a good advice. +1.

Comment: I misunderstood your 2nd bullet, so removed that comment.

Comment: 1. Yes, I think you should. Or you could use a [ReentrantLock](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html) too.

Comment: 4. In this case I'd rename the `prerequisite` variable to `minimumRequiredJavaVersionPrerequisite` :-)

Answer (score 2):

I do not see any issues with your code, however,
A few questions,

- Why is F0 abstract? (why not an interface)?
- Why do you need isInitialized? cant you null check the content? even if init could throw, there doesn't seem to be a difference.
- What happens if the initialization results in an exception? Do you want to retry each time .get is called? or do you want to remember that it was unsuccessful?
- I am also curious, why did you opt to use initializedAs rather than using just new Lazy<String>()?

Comment: 1. The other `F{n}` abstract classes contain abstract methods, and therefore cannot be interfaces. So for the sake of consistency, I made `F0` an abstract class. But yes, I agree, it should really be an interface.

Comment: 2. To allow `null` as a valid value. In the retrospect, I cannot think of a case where I would require that. So perhaps, yes, I should do away with `isInitialized`, and add a `null` check in `init`.

Comment: 3. A very good point. I did not think about it. I think it would make sense to retry the initialization on each access if it failed on last access.

Comment: 4. For better type inference, and less redundancy (at use site). In case of direct constructor use, user has to supply the type parameter. In case of static methods, it can be inferred from the type of reference to which the object is being assigned. (This is in the same spirit as say Guava's `Lists.newArrayList`.)

Comment: Overall, a good advice. +1.

Comment: Regarding 2nd bullet, if `init.apply` happens to return null, then it will unnecessarily get called every time `get` is accessed. It appears I will be needing `isInitialized` after all.

Comment: @missingfaktor Yes certainly, I was only wondering if that was your intension.

Comment: If returning null in init.apply is an indication of failure, any particular reason you chose that rather than allowing apply throw an exception?

Comment: I did not understand that last comment.

Comment: I assume that you kept isInitialized because init.apply may return null on failure. Since your interface for apply does not have a "throws" I assume it is not expected that an exception happen. I was wondering why you chose to use null as a construction-failure indicator rather than allow apply to throw an exception on that event. Perhaps I am confusing some part of your design?

Comment: No, you misunderstood. The reason I am using `isInitialized` is because I want to allow `null` as a valid value. In other words, it has no special privileges over any other values `contents` can take. It is not used as a construction-failure indicator.

Comment: ok, that is reasonable.